# How to check if a Azure Cosmos DB client connection is successful with Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way/method to check if my Cosmos DB client is successfully connected to the Azure Cosmos DB using the Java SDK?

Comment: Just send a query?

Comment: @Robert Does creating a client instance send any queries to the Azure servers?

Answer (score 2):

In general you should have Client Object generated, you can just check using

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder()
.endpoint(serviceEndpoint)
.key(key)
.buildClient();
```

then,

```
if (cosmosClient != null) {
```

Comment: Would it be also useful to query a dummy endpoint to make be even more sure the connection is working?

Comment: You would get an error , catch that error